# WebMock stub_request not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, webmock

In my rails project, one of the initialisers requests and fetches certain data from `S3`.

```
S3.buckets[CONFIG['aws']['cdn_bucket']].objects['object_name'].read
```

This breaks the rspec test suite which uses `webmock` gem

```
WebMock.allow_net_connect!(:net_http_connect_on_start => true)
```

I get the following error when I try to run the test suite

```
WebMock::NetConnectNotAllowedError

You can stub this request with the following snippet:

stub_request(:get, "https://bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/object_name").with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'', 'Authorization'=>'AWS AKxxxxxx:Hyxxxxxxxxxx', 'Content-Type'=>'', 'Date'=>'Thu, 14 Apr 2016 15:10:18 GMT', 'User-Agent'=>'aws-sdk-ruby/1.60.2 ruby/1.8.7 i686-darwin15.3.0'}).to_return(:status => 200, :body => "", :headers => {})
```

Adding this stub does not fix the error. Infact, adding any of the following does not seem to make any change:

```
WebMock.stub_request(:any, /.*amazonaws.*/).with(:headers => {'Accept'=>'*/*', 'Accept-Encoding'=>'', 'Authorization'=>'AWS AKIxxxxxxxxxx:MSxxxxxxxx'}).to_return(:status => 200, :body => "stubbed response", :headers => {})
```

```
WebMock.stub_request(:any, /.*amazonaws.*/).to_return(:status => 200, :body => "stubbed response", :headers => {})
```

What is it that I am missing here? The detailed header in the error message does not seem to make sense here to allow all kinds of requests to `S3`

**EDIT:**

I just noticed that adding `WebMock.disable!` to the `spec_helper` also results in no change. Am I not adding the stub to the right place? Where should it be added if not in the `spec_helper`?

Comment: Did you try to intercept the request with a proxy? Just to be sure that the request is being made to amazonaws.com.

Comment: @Deva since adding `WebMock.disable!` changed nothing, I figured that the snippet was being added to the wrong place. I had to add it to the initialiser script directly and that fixed it. The request url was correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After sleeping over it, it was clear that the `stub_request` was being added to the wrong place. Adding it directly to the initialiser could have fixed this but that would have broken all other environments as the gem `webmock` is included for test env only.

Hence adding the following code snippet to the script fixed this

```
begin
  require 'webmock'
  WebMock.stub_request(:any, /testimonial/).to_return(:body => '')
rescue LoadError
end

S3.buckets[CONFIG['aws']['cdn_bucket']].objects['object_name'].read
```

This makes a `stub_request` if the gem is included else simply goes on as nothing happened.